# How to know when a time picker is closed?

Tags: android, android-studio

I made this Timepicker to ask for an hour to the user. I call it in a fragment named Extendeditemview() which implements the OnTimeSetListener, how can i know when the Timepicker is closed?, Can i use the fragment tag to know that? if i call the timepicker in different places in the code with different fragment tags, can i differenciate which one is in the listener function? And the last question, can i do the same thing that im doing now but with interfaces? (not implementing the listener on the fragment, but in the time picker class)

```
class TimepickerAlarm: DialogFragment(){

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        val c: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        val hour: Int = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
        val minute: Int = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), Extendenitemview() as OnTimeSetListener, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }
}
```

In the fragment:

```
class Extendenitemview : Fragment(),OnTimeSetListener{
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
        ...
        val newFragment: DialogFragment = TimepickerAlarm()
        fragmentManager?.let { it1 -> newFragment.show(it1, "timePicker")
        ...
       }
override fun onTimeSet(p0: TimePicker?, p1: Int, p2: Int) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [onDismiss](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/DialogFragment#onDismiss(android.content.DialogInterface)) method in DialogFragment, so you can override it in your TimepickerAlarm class to get notified about dialog dismiss event.
**Remember** to call super method, because DialogFragment uses it internally

```
@CallSuper
public void onDismiss(@NonNull DialogInterface dialog){
     super.onDismiss(dialog);
     //Do your stuff
}
```

(sorry that's java idk kotlin)